# OpenVPN Windows 10 : how to access computers inside the LAN?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to install a VPN between my laptop and my network at home, and all my computers (except my AsusTor NAS) use Windows 10 (I know it would be easier with Linux but I've got no choice). So far, I can communicate with the Windows machine where the OpenVPN server is, but **I can't reach my other computers**.

Here are my **[network plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2IPh.png)**, and my ovpn config files:

- server.ovpn

  ```
  port 1194
  proto udp
  dev tun

  ca "P:\\Serveurs\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
  cert "P:\\Serveurs\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
  key "P:\\Serveurs\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"
  dh "P:\\Serveurs\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh1024.pem"
  tls-auth "P:\\Serveurs\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 0

  topology subnet
  server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
  push "route 192.168.63.0 255.255.255.0"

  ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
  client-to-client
  keepalive 10 120
  cipher AES-256-CBC
  persist-key
  persist-tun
  status openvpn-status.log
  verb 3
  explicit-exit-notify 1
  ```
- aa-laptop.ovpn (client):

  ```
  client
  dev tun
  proto udp
  remote dns.perso.fr 1194
  resolv-retry infinite
  nobind
  persist-key
  persist-tun

  ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\ca.crt"
  cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\AA-LAPTOP.crt"
  key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\AA-LAPTOP.key"

  remote-cert-tls server
  tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\ta.key" 1
  cipher AES-256-CBC
  verb 3
  ```

As you see, I can connect my laptop and my server with OpenVPN, and when it's done I can access my server shares by typing `\\10.8.0.1` and `\\192.168.63.4`, the two methods work, that's great! But I can't reach anything else in my home LAN, neither my computer with `\\192.168.63.2` nor my NAS `\\192.168.63.7`.

It might be a server-side missing-config-param problem or a bridgy-thing, I don't know. But the only piece of help I found use `route add gw` linux commands which obviously can't work on Windows.

Thanks for advance for your help !

Regards,

Comment: Maybe you just need to add something like route 192.168.63.0 255.255.255.0 together with your push route rule to tell the vpn server to route that traffic into the vpn. I can't test it

Comment: Thanks a lot, @FedericoGalli ! That was it, I just had to execute a cmd at launch :
`route ADD 192.168.63.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.63.1`
And now, I can access my other computers :D You saved my life, mate !

Comment: Sometimes vpn can be tricky :-)

Comment: Simply add the correct `dhcp-option` to the server config:  `push                'dhcp-option    DNS 192.168.63.1` and `push                'dhcp-option    WINS 192.168.63.1'`, where `192.168.63.1` is the LAN DNS server.  Also, `AES-256-CBC` is overkill and completely unncessary, as `AES-128-CBC` will remain uncrackable for about a decade or so, if not longer.  All you're doing is severly limiting your throughput for no advance in security.  A better option, if there's serious security concerns for the data passing through, would be to change the `rekey` timing and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Federico Galli](https://superuser.com/users/508888/federico-galli) answered my question, in addition to a correct OpenVPN configuration, I needed to launch :

```
route ADD 192.168.63.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.63.1
```

Personally, I made a `routage.bat` file launched at Windows startup because the route is not persisted.

Again, thank you a lot [Federico Galli](https://superuser.com/users/508888/federico-galli), it's working perfectly now !

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to simply add the correct `dhcp-option` to the server config?  `push                'dhcp-option    DNS 192.168.63.1` and `push                'dhcp-option    WINS 192.168.63.1'`

Comment: Any further advice here? What was your exact final config? As far as I can tell mine matches yours.  Did you add push route on the server config AND route on the client? Did you add the gateway to the same config on BOTH config files? Assuming the 'route add' command was run on the openvpn server host & that server host was on the 192.168.63 subnet e.g. same as rest of your LAN?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very simply with a single line in [OpenVPN using *its* route command](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/setting-up-routing/), no need for a .bat file.

To show an example using your client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote dns.perso.fr 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\AA-LAPTOP.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\AA-LAPTOP.key"

remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Config\\ta.key" 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
# Add this line here
route 192.168.63.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.63.1
```

That's it! You just add `route 192.168.63.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.63.1` to the client .ovpn. For other network setups, the syntax is as follows:

`route SUBNET SUBNET-MASK GATEWAY`

So, if you use the [CIDR range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) 192.168.0.0/16, and 192.168.1.1 is your gateway, you would do:
`route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.1`

Importantly, and helpfully, it will (internally) use whatever commands are native to the client's system to actually *implement* that, so for Windows, it would execute `route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.1`, Linux/OSX would be their built-in routing methods. It makes the file more portable this way.

As you might have figured out, since `push` just sends a setting to the client, you were incredibly close with your original server .ovpn:

`push "route 192.168.63.0 255.255.255.0"` is missing the gateway.

If you had added 192.168.63.1 to the end, it would've worked. You can do it either from the client-side, or server-side, but I think that it's better to do it on the client-side, as it would be easier to edit the client .ovpn if you needed to access files on a different network, with a different subnet, for instance, but it does depend on the deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is create a new virtual network card in your Windows 10 box, given it an IP address, and made a remote system ping it. This is all standard stuff, but in software instead of e.g. plugging an Ethernet adapter into a USB port.

The problem now is routing, which only Microsoft's Server products support natively. There are methods such as [Internet Connection Sharing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9) (select the VPN adapter instead of the Hosted Virtual in that article) which turns your Windows 10 system into a mini Internet Router. It unfortunately won't allow your LAN devices to initiate connections to a VPN client, but otherwise works rather well.

Another alternative is very dodgy, and [enables native routing in your Windows 10 client](http://keepthetech.com/2016/01/enable-ip-routing-on-windows10.html) by very low-level changes directly in the registry. Proceed with caution. In fact, probably don't do that at all.

If you really want flexibility, look into a buying low-cost router with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), both of which support OpenVPN and native routing, with nice graphical interfaces. You can get by with a $40 device like the [TP-Link WA-901ND](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002YETVXC), but check the supported devices list on their websites.

If you're feeling adventurous and really want to get to grips with Linux, a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) will do extremely well.

The added benefit is these low-power devices don't need to be on constantly.

Comment: I personally run a [TP-Link WR1043ND v2](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd), [TP-Link WA091ND v3](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa901nd) and [Raspberry Pi 2 B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) with OpenVPN v2.3 for both roving clients and site-to-site VPNs, and they Just Work :)

Answer (score 0):

route ADD -p parameter adds permanent. no need to made bat file

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This looks like a comment on Aurélien Achat's answer rather than a new solution.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post comments.  But even as a new user, you could consider proposing an edit on that answer with this as supplementary information.