# connecting to devices on laptop's LAN through VPN connection

Tags: vpn, lan

I am currently running an instance of OpenVPN client on my colleague's laptop which has a number of devices on its LAN connected to the ethernet port through an unmanaged switch (192.168.1.x/24) and this laptop is connected to the internet through office wifi to reach the OpenVPN cloud server.

My question is how would I configure the network adaptors on his laptop so that I can access the devices on the LAN of my colleague's laptop from my office computer which is running another instance of OpenVPN client connected to the same OpenVPN cloud server.

Comment: @harrymc's answer [`client-to-client`], in conjunction with adding at least one `dhcp-option` to the client config _([example](https://superuser.com/a/1494782/529800))_ and inbound firewall rules on the remote PC _(the example link is for a server config, which pushes the `dhcp-option` to the client, however this can also be individually added to a client's client config)_.

Comment: @jin167 IP forwarding needs to be enabled (and allowed in the system firewall, if any) on the colleague's laptop. Also, either add route for the VPN subnet on its LAN hosts, or configure source NAT (a.k.a. IP masquerade) on the laptop. In the "normal" OpenVPN case, in addition to pushing route (for the LAN subnet) to the VPN client(s), `iroute` also need to be specified properly on the VPN server (to tell it that the traffics for subnet should be forwarded to the laptop). But since I have no experience with "OpenVPN cloud", I have no idea how you should configure the equivalent exactly.

Comment: @jin167 Whether a route for the LAN subnet in concern needs to be configured on the server probably depends on whether `client-to-client` is used (yes for no, vice versa). Therefore if the LAN subnet conflicts with one the server is in, `client-to-client` is probably a nice trick to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the OpenVPN server does not allow clients to connect to each
other. To change it, you must configure the server, and not the client.

You can enable it by uncommenting this line in the `server.conf` file
on the server:

```
;client-to-client
```

So it should look like this:

```
client-to-client
```

Then restart the openvpn service:

```
sudo service openvpn restart
```

Comment: Accessing a client's *site* is from another client host is different from accessing a *client host*. The key to the OP is `iroute`. `client-to-client` merely eliminates the need of IP forwarding to be enabled / allowed and route for the client's site subnet to be added on the VPN server. The thing is, the story (in terms of configuration details) might be quite different when the case is `OpenVPN cloud` (no idea if you are even allowed to edit a conf file).

Comment: More than `client-to-client` is [required](https://superuser.com/a/1494782/529800), as at least one _(if not two depending on the use case)_ `dhcp-option` must also be set in the client config, else the VPN server has no clue how to route that traffic, and firewall rules would likely be required on the endpoint since endpoints usually block inbound traffic that didn't originate on the endpoint by default.

Comment: @JW0914 Please. How is `dhcp-option` even relevant at all to `VPN server has no clue how to route that traffic`? Please at least read the OP carefully (`OpenVPN client on my colleague's laptop` / `access the devices on the LAN of my colleague's laptop`)  and get to know about how OpenVPN *actually* works by reading some documentation (e.g. the manual or [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans).

Comment: @JW0914 Let alone the fact that `client-to-client` is not even directly related to the goal, firewall rules on the VPN server does not apply to client to client traffics when `client-to-client` is enabled, as the traffics does not even get out of the tunnel/program on the *server* in that case (which is why in some case you want to have that disabled and rely on the IP forwarding of the OS' IP stack for that). (While on the other hand, firewall rules and IP forwarding setting always matter on the *client* that serves as the "gateway" to the "LAN" in concern.)

Comment: @TomYan The VPN tunnel is aware only of the IPs assigned by the VPN, not LAN routes, so if only `client-to-client` is added, the OP will be able to access the other client's PC, but not other devices on the remote PC's LAN _(what the OP is requesting)_; in order to do so,  a `dhcp-option DNS`  for the LAN subnet must be in the client config for traffic to be routed. I have the exact same setup on OpenWrt, but if you doubt it, please test with only `client-to-client` _(it's why I linked to an answer that address this very thing in my prior comment as an example)_

Comment: @JW0914 `iroute`, end of story. (Seriously, it does not even make common / logical sense to relate DNS to routing.)

Comment: To put it in an even clearer way, by default all the traffics will escape from the tunnel on the server. So in the usual case which you access other network(s) via (only) the server, you only need to push/configure routes on the clients. However, when it comes to the case that you access other network(s) via *one of the clients*, you will need to configure corresponding `iroute` additionally on the *server* to tell it *which client* the traffics should go to so that they can reach the corresponding network (which is why `iroute` is not placed in the main server conf but a ccd file).

Comment: Btw `client-to-client` does not actually make clients connect to each other directly with their public IPs (i.e. it's not "P2P"). It merely makes the server perform "early" / "internal" forwarding. (So traffics has a client's VPN IP has destination, and IIRC, those that has destination covered by an `iroute`, will not escape from the tunnel when `client-to-client` is enabled; but even without `client-to-client`, IP forwarding on the server can still make corresponding traffics goes back into the tunnel to a client, and *"which client"* is still determined by `iroute`.)

Comment: @Tom Yan, JW0914, harrymc

Hey guys, thank you so much for your response :) I used to have the OpenVPN community server and client all set up for testing and all functions including client-to-client used to work perfectly fine but we had to move away from using the community and chose to go with the cloud version due to security concerns and management issues. Now, everything would have been easy if I could get my colleague to use the router that I have been using for my test setup as routing becomes really easy but now I am in a situation where I need to do all routings on his laptop.

Comment: My current setup is:

VPN Client VPN Client VPN IP:10.0.1.3 wifi VPN IP:10.0.0.2 |Colleague's Laptop|<----->|Router/Modem|<---->|OpenVPN Cloud|<---->|My Laptop|

LAN1 (wifi): LAN: 10.0.0.x/24 10.0.0.32

LAN2 (ethernet port):
192.168.1.x/24 device1: 192.168.1.1 device2: 192.168.1.2

It's easy enough to access the devices on LAN1 (OpenVPN cloud makes this process really simple) but I'm not really sure how to route the connection between LAN1 and LAN2.

Comment: In essence, a colleague's laptop has 2 NICs (wifi and ethernet port) and I'm not quite sure how to do the routing if there are 2 LANs where 1 of them (wifi) is used for connecting to the Cloud and the other is for connecting to devices that are physically attached to his laptop through the ethernet port.